# Should DTOs contain embedded entities or should I return "flat" DTOs that only have the IDs?

Tags: rest, mapping, api-design, dto

In the past, my DTOs have been a direct map of the entity. However, I am now in a scenario where all we really need is the ID of a nested object so we can then do the DB lookup if needed. It looks something like this

```
public class UserDto {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<Integer> groupIds;
}
```

But the entity looks like this

```
public class UserEntity {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<UserGroupEntity> userGroups;    
}
```

Is this a common practice? Should I just have the DTO mapped directly from the entity and have embeded UserGroup DTOs?

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with option number one, only including the `ids` of other entities. The DTO can otherwise become quite bloated after a while, leading to a lot of unnecessary database lookups.

I only go for option number two if the DTO never makes any sense without the containing entities. But this is almost never the case, and it's difficult and dangerous to assume that you know what information all future users of your DTO will want to have.

---

When it comes to the API endpoint design (assuming you go for option one) you can let the client fetch `User`s and `UserGroup`s by calling the following endpoints:

```
/users/:id
```

```
/users/:id/usergroups
```

This is so that the client doesn't have to wait for the `User` fetch to finish before fetching the `UserGroup`s. This follows RESTful principles and can e.g. be done in parallell from the client.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly my thought process as well. I really like that pathing example that you gave. One further question.

Since the entity is using the @JoinColumn annotation to actually pull the relevant entities into the list inside the User entity, is this database hop being made anyway? I am using the fetchType EAGER in this annotation, but I figure since I am reading the IDs anyway, that hop must have already been made.

Comment: @Roflsausage What DB lookups are being made depends on your table mapping, enable more logging to see each query being made. I avoid using eager fetching whenever possible for this exact reason; you don't want to force the application to query data the client doesn't ask for.